# gulp-git. Clone remote repo from bitbucket

Tags: git, gulp, bitbucket

I want to clone the repo from bitbucket using a gulp. 
My gulp task:

```
gulp.task('cloneSub', function () {
git.clone('https://UserName@bitbucket.org/XXXXX/XXXXX.git', {cwd: './gitRepo/'}, function (err) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
})});
```

Result:

[11:49:25] Starting 'cloneSub'...

[11:49:37] Finished 'cloneSub' after 12 s

and further, nothing happens

in my /gitRepo created an empty folder with the name of the project

project in bitbucket is private.

I can not clone a private repository in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Need send your password in https query

```
https://UserName:Password@bitbucket.org/XXXXX/XXXXX.git
```